# why printing formatted text stays the same even when changing the variable that is inside the formatted text (Python)

Tags: python

So I have this simple code:

```
num = 0
x = f"Hello number {num}"
    
while True:
    print(num)
    print(x)
    num += 1
```

What I expected the output to be:

> 1
> Hello number 1

but what it does output is:

> 1
> Hello number 0

The number in the text didn't change
I tried to understand why but I couldn't.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string is formatted when you create it at the top. You can format it on every iteration before printing to get the result you want.

```py
num = 0
x = "Hello number {}"
    
while True:
    print(num)
    print(x.format(num))
    num += 1
```

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[@Gokberk Yaltirakli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978197/gokberk-yaltirakli) explained why you don't get the expected output as well as provided solution.

Another option is to use [template string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings)

> Template strings provide simpler string substitutions as described in
> [PEP 292](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292). A primary use case for template strings is for
> internationalization (i18n) since in that context, the simpler syntax
> and functionality makes it easier to translate than other built-in
> string formatting facilities in Python. As an example of a library
> built on template strings for i18n, see the [flufl.i18n](http://flufli18n.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

```
from string import Template

t=Template("Hello number $num")

for n in range(5):
    print(t.substitute(num=n))
```

output

```
Hello number 0
Hello number 1
Hello number 2
Hello number 3
Hello number 4
```

Note, there are also powerful third-party template engines like [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/)